# Why is an ephemeral key used in creating a digital signature?

Tags: private-key, signature, cryptography

When creating the 'S' component of a digital signature, both the actual private key and an ephemeral private key are used.

The reasoning I've read is to ensure that the sender’s actual private key can’t be calculated by attackers watching signed transactions on the Ethereum network.

How would an attacker be able to calculate a private key anyway? Is the purpose of the ephemeral key to simply further obfuscate?